# performSelectorOnMainThread is not waiting to finish

Tags: multithreading, xcode, animation

I have a thread which performs some tasks.

At the end I want to run a selector to hide an image with animation.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finishUpdate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

I am setting the duration to 10 seconds:

```
- (void) finishUpdate {

    UIImageView *myImage = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:788];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0f];
    myImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 80);
    myImage.alpha = 0.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But it is disappearing instantly and the thread continues immediately.

Do you know how to make my thread to wait or how to display this simple animation?

Comment: `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` usually only returns a valid context when inside your `drawRect:` method.  But that shouldn't matter, as the value passed as `context` to the `beginAnimations:context:` method is for your own use, not the system's.

Comment: @Kristopher: I used the same method at the beginning of the thread - to show the image and it worked as expected.

Comment: What I mean is that you don't need to call `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`.  You can just pass `nil` as the `context` parameter to `beginAnimations:context:` and it will make no difference.  But that has nothing to do with why it's not working.

Comment: Do you ever set the image's `hidden` property true?  If so, that would make it disappear right away, regardless of any animation going on.

Comment: @Kristopher: I work only with alpha property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of waiting for the selector to finish, I used `sleepForTimeInterval:` method to pause my thread, using the same duration as my animation.

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.3];
```

Answer (score 2):

It is normal behavior for the method to return immediately. `[UIView commitAnimations]` does not wait for the animation to finish (or any other method you use).

Kristopher Johnson is right that you shouldn't use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` in this context. It is used in `drawRect:` or whenever there is a valid graphics context.

The animation context does not relate to a graphics context. Just pass NULL if you don't need any context in some animation delegate.